# RESTful view counter

Tags: http, rest, resources, counter

I would like to count the access to a resource, but HTTP GET should not modify a resource. The counter should be displayed with the resource. A similar case would be to store the last access.

What is the REST way to realize a view counter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating a counter in reaction to a GET is actually not a violation of the HTTP protocol.  You are not modifying the resource you are getting, or any other resource that the client can control.
If a server was not allowed to do any updates in response to a GET then log files would violate the HTTP contract!

Here is the relevant part in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1),:

> 9.1.1 Safe Methods
>
> Implementors should be aware that the
>   software represents the user in their
>   interactions over the Internet, and
>   should be careful to allow the user to
>   be aware of any actions they might
>   take which may have an unexpected
>   significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been
>   established that the GET and HEAD
>   methods SHOULD NOT have the
>   significance of taking an action other
>   than retrieval. These methods ought to
>   be considered "safe". This allows user
>   agents to represent other methods,
>   such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a
>   special way, so that the user is made
>   aware of the fact that a possibly
>   unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to
>   ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of
>   performing a GET request; in fact,
>   some dynamic resources consider that a
>   feature. The important distinction
>   here is that the user did not request
>   the side-effects, so therefore cannot
>   be held accountable for them.

The first significant thing to note is that it says "SHOULD NOT" and not "MUST NOT".  There are cases where side effects are valid.

The second critical line is last line that highlights the fact that the user did not make a request with any desire to make a change and therefore it is up to the server to ensure that nothing happens that would be contradictory to the clients expectations.  This is the essence of the "uniform interface constraint".  The server should do what the client expects.  This is very different than the client issuing

```
GET /myresource?operation=delete
```

In this case, the client thinks they are doing a retrieval. If the client application is respecting the hypermedia constraint then the contents of URL are completely opaque, so the only information the client can understand is the verb GET.  If the server actually does a delete then, that is a clear violation of the uniform interface constraint.

Updating an internal counter is not a violation of the uniform interface constraint.  If the counter was to be included in the representation being retrieved then you have a whole new set of problems, but I am going to assume that is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation! What problems would you expect if the counter would be included in the retrieved representation?

Comment: It would mess with caching. Conceptually, your resource has not changed, but your representation would.  It's sort of weird. Actually, counters are kind of screwed by caching anyway.

Comment: Excellent answer I just had a very similar question and this just nailed it perfectly!